# How do I find the lateral surface area of an elliptical cone? (not a frustum)

Tags: differential-geometry, conic-sections

The formula for the lateral surface area of a right circular cone is $\pi*r*l$ where $r$ is the circle's radius.

But ellipse has a semi-major axis as well as a semi-minor one.

Which one of them should be implemented in the formula and  how?

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticCone.html

Comment: A right circular cone of semi vertical cone angle $ \alpha$ and height $h$  when intersected at angle $\beta$ to symmetry axes can have $ (a,b)= h \tan \alpha \;( csc \beta,1) $. Please check

Comment: @MathLover Tanks for your help; the final formula lacks the slant height ($l$). So if we have an oblique elliptical cone the same formula is applicable?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It works for volume but not for surface area. You will have to set up an integral. Even if they wrote in terms of slant height, it would change based on $\theta$. What is your exact need? Can you give more context?

Comment: I have a right circular cone cross-sectioned to give a planar ellipse. I need to find the lateral area of the upper cone which is an oblique elliptic cone.

Comment: Is the cone $z^2 = x^2 + y^2$? What is the equation of the plane intersecting it?

Comment: Not in that way; but I have calculated that oblique cone's height; also I have found the semi axes of the base. also I have found two slant heights.

Comment: But the slant height changes with $\theta$ and based on where we are on the ellipse, we will be at $a \cos\theta + b\sin\theta$ distance from the center of the ellipse. We need to find slant height equation for that. It is easier to calculate lateral surface area if we know - i) original height and radius of the right circular cone and ii) how it was cut (plane that cut it will be the best) or at least whether it was cut starting at a point on the base.

Comment: I know the amounts of original cone, but I don't know how do I find the equation of the cutting plane.

Comment: Can Ian Barnett's answer on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1434572/lateral-area-of-oblique-cylinder-and-cone) question help me find my answer? Look at his link too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your cone is a section of a circular right cone, then a simple answer is possible.

Let $\alpha$ be the semi-aperture of the cone, $\beta$ the angle between the axis of the cone and the normal to the intersecting plane, $q$ the distance of the vertex from the intersection between the plane and the axis of the cone.

A parametric equation of the conic surface is then:
$$
x=t\sin\alpha\cos\phi,\quad 
y=t\sin\alpha\sin\phi,\quad
z=t\cos\alpha, 
$$
where $t$ is the distance from vertex $(0,0,0)$ and $\phi$ is the azimuthal angle about $z$-axis (which is the axis of the cone).

A suitable equation for the plane is simply $z=(\tan\beta) x+q$, and substituting here $x$ and $z$ from above one gets:
$$
t={q\over \cos\alpha-\tan\beta\sin\alpha\cos\phi},
$$
which is the distance from the vertex to a generic point $P$ on the ellipse at the base of the cone.

The area of the lateral surface is then:
$$
A=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^t r\sin\alpha\,dr\,d\phi=
{q^2\sin\alpha\over2\cos^2\alpha}
\int_0^{2\pi}{d\phi\over (1-\tan\alpha\tan\beta\cos\phi)^2}=
{\pi q^2\sin\alpha\over\cos^2\alpha}
{1\over(1-\tan^2\alpha\tan^2\beta)^{3/2}}.
$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you; but can you please explain what the normal to the intersecting plane is?

Comment: It is a line perpendicular to the plane. In other words, $90°-\beta$ is the angle between the plane and the axis of the cone.

Comment: @EtackSxchange May I know if this answer has been of help? And, if it hasn't, why?